# Android : How to notify the user when the Application is not running

Tags: android, notifications, android-c2dm, foreground

I am new to Android and have a problem with the Notifications. I know that this topic has been taken up earlier as well but I just wanted to know if there is any other way to go about it.

Problem : In my application I want that the user is notified that he/she has entered in the radius of a particular location. I have the functionality working when the application is alive and in the foreground. I will however want that the user is also notified when the application is not working and not there in the foreground.

In the previous posts I have found out that this can be done by using something called as the C2DM. Altough I am not much aware of it but by using C2DM I would be introducing an extra network trip. My question is that the only way to go about it? Can't this functionality be done any other way round, something locally like something of a daemon thread of sorts?

Also if C2DM is only the way, and as my application is not in my foreground will the C2DM also inform once the user reaches the radius of a particular location?

Will like to thank you all in advance. Please do let me know if any one of you have faced a situation/problem/requirement similar to this before and also if you can highlight the way forward for this?

Comment: C2DM is for getting notifications from a server, which probably isn't what you want.  (Unless you have a server that's constantly monitoring the device's location, which probably isn't what a privacy-conscious user wants.)

Comment: Hi @Wyzard, yeah exactly I don't have a server tracking the user's device locations :) ... I swear ;)... searching for an alternate way to go about this... Thanks for your comments please do let me know if you think of any.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the functionality working when the application is alive and in the foreground. I will however want that the user is also notified when the application is not working and not there in the foreground.

[Use `addProximityAlert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) on `LocationManager`, and then it will not matter whether your app is in the foreground or not.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare ... thanks for your comment... I have a list of addresses so do I need to apply the ProximityAlert on all of them individually?

Comment: @user1593953: If you have additional questions regarding the use of `addProximityAlert()`, please use the "Ask Question" button in the upper-right corner to ask a new question.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare ... I have posted another question regarding [ProximityAlert with a BroadcastReceiver not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994694/proximityalert-with-a-broadcastreceiver-not-working). Please if you can have a look at the code and share your views on where I might have gone wrong it would be really great and helpful of you. Thanks in advance.